# Getting image info anonymously through Imgur API in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, imgur

I'm trying to anonymously get image data (like image sizes) through the Imgur Version 3 API through C#. Their documentation states

> The API requires each client to use OAuth 2 authentication. This means
>   you'll have to register your application, and generate an access_code
>   if you'd like to log in as a user.
>
> For public read-only and anonymous resources, such as getting image
>   info, looking up user comments, etc. all you need to do is send an
>   authorization header with your client_id in your requests. This also
>   works if you'd like to upload images anonymously (without the image
>   being tied to an account), or if you'd like to create an anonymous
>   album. This lets us know which application is accessing the API.
>
> Authorization: Client-ID YOUR_CLIENT_ID

So I added the Client-ID as a header to my HttpWebRequest. Here's my code below.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/id/8ABRUYt");
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID XXXXX");
Stream response = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

I get a 404 error, but that image clearly exists -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NJK2.jpg (Picture of a milky way bar). Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first line should read

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.imgur.com/3/image/8ABRUYt");
```

The correct url is "https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{id}" - {id} being your picture ID.

Your post helped me greatly getting started on simply viewing a picture from imgur! I would vote you up, but that requires 15 reputation :( I'll be sure to rep you, when I can :)